# UWP IScrollSnapPointsInfo floating point issues

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

While implementing IScrollSnapPointsInfo the method "GetRegularSnapPoints" receives a parameter offset (float) and returns a float. Those are the snappoints. Actual width and height of a frameworkelement is "double". The snappoints being float i'm facing precision issues. Please help in understanding.

Comment: "Actual width and height of a frameworkelement is "double"." Could you please elaborate on this "double" behavior and show how you implemented `GetRegularSnapPoints` to help us further check the problem for you?